# Is there a way to add Teams meeting info by default for all meeting requests?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

We have a lot of remotes so we often use Teams for online meetings.  However, Teams doesn't let you "Join" a meeting unless you click the little "Teams" button when you're sending out the calendar invite:

[image]

When you click this button, it adds a link to the invite and makes it officially a Teams meeting.  The last 600 times, I've forgotten to do this and people message me saying they can't join my meeting.  I have to go in, click the button, and send a meeting request update.  Is there any way to make it do all this by default?  I want every single meeting to be a Teams meeting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click New Teams Meeting when creating a new meeting.

[image]

To avoid clicking “wrong” New Meeting button, we can customize ribbon to only show “New Teams Meeting” option. To do this, please go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon.
Under Home(Calendar), select New and click Remove. Move Teams Meeting to the top.

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea!  I use the keyboard shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+Q) to create meeting requests because it's become muscle memory after like 20 years, but perhaps there's a way to remap shortcut keys too.  I'll look into it!